# Using font awesome for setting up the look of glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have the following html code:

```
<a href="test">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

I'd like to change how this arrow looks like in some ways: make it smaller, thinner. I heard it could be done via font awesome. I did some research but couldn't understand how I could do this. Could you guys help me or give a general direction?

Some of the gems I'm using:

```
ruby "2.1.1"

gem "rails", "4.1.0"

gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.2"
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1.0"
gem "haml-rails"
```

Comment: glyphicon automatically spans across the parent container and takes the size of current font size. You can override the color and further look by addressing it in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

change the font size(to make icons smaller) and font weight (to make it thinner) of the span.
it will do the trick. treat glyphicons like text.

html:

```
<a href="test">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right right-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

css:

```
.right-arrow{
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

Comment: but I'd like not to change the size of the font, I'd like only to make the icon smaller.

Comment: it will not change the overall font size, will just fix the size of the arrow icon

Comment: what about font awesome then_

Comment: Font awesome is another library like glyphicons but font awesome haa more rich and bigger collection

Comment: that was my question: how to apply font awesome in my case? –  Alex 1 hour ago